# Starting jackd after using other audio

Tags: audio, jack

I know this is probably a common question.
When I start jackd after first booting, everything works fine.
If I use another audio (such as Banshee or Youtube, etc) jack won't start.

From what I gather, the audio server is committed to whatever was running before. I guess what my question is; how do I free up the server to allow jackd to run? (without having to reboot before I record)

Comment: Is there another sound server such as PulseAudio installed on your computer? It's possible that it takes control of the soundcard when you launch an application. It can be a reason for jackd to be unable to reclaim it after. In that case, you may get some help here: http://jackaudio.org/pulseaudio_and_jack. If any of those tips was useful to you, feel free to post your own answer here.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was unclear, but I am assuming that Pulse is taking over and letting go. I will look at the link, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: what is your distribution and version? ubuntu* and pulseaudio should reconfigure themselves to allow jackd to take over. Do you stil need help with that?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/572120/15729

Comment: @lgeorget The link you posted is broken. http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html might be the new location.